# Overriding configuration variables from cypress.env.json

Tags: javascript, configuration, cypress

## TL;DR:

I am trying to override the `baseUrl` value from `cypress.json` using my `cypress.env.json` file, but I can't seem to figure out how. Is there a way to do this?

## Background

Setting **environment variables** in the `cypress.json` file and later overriding them in `cypress.env.json` is as [easy as pie](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html). In `cypress.json`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "someVariable": "originalValue"
  }
}
```

... and in `cypress.env.json`:

```
{
  "someVariable": "newValue"
}
```

Regarding **configuration variables**, [the documentation states](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Overriding-Configuration):

> If your environment variables match a standard configuration key, then instead of setting an `environment variable` they will instead override the configuration value.

However, if I try setting `baseUrl` from `cypress.json`...

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://example.com/setFromCypress.json",
  "env": {
    "someVariable": "originalValue"
  }
}
```

... and overriding it in `cypress.env.json` ...

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://example.com/setFromCypress.env.json",
  "someVariable": "newValue"
}
```

... then `someVariable` is overriden, but the existing `baseUrl` remains unchanged (and a `baseUrl` appears inside the object placed at the `env` key):

[image: A picture of the Cypress configuration when setting baseUrl from both cypress.json and cypress.env.json]

I have no problem when setting `baseUrl` in `cypress.json` and later overriding it in the command line using `CYPRESS_BASE_URL`:

```
$ export CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://example.com/setFromCommandLine
```

Then, the original `baseUrl` is overriden:

[image: A picture of the Cypress configuration when setting baseUrl from cypress.json, cypress.env.json and the command line]

To summarize: Am I missing something in the documentation, or is something missing in the documentation?

Comment: I think it's a bug.. would create an [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new)

Comment: Done: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/909

Comment: I think you can add that as an answer, @DanSwain. Just do so, and I'll give you the checkmark. ;)

Comment: Done @vages.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the above post, it was explained in the [related github issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/909) that this is not considered a bug. Variables from `cypress.env.json` are loaded into the `environmentVariables` variable within the overall config (despite what the current documentation would lead you to believe).  The overall config file is *cypress.json*.  In the github issue, I've provided backup concerning why the current explanation is confusing.

Answer (score 11):

A simple workaround: in plugins/index.js do

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  if(config.hasOwnProperty('env') &&  config.env.hasOwnProperty('baseUrl')){
      config.baseUrl = config.env.baseUrl;
  }
  return config
}
```

Comment: that's an excellent workaround to a widely encountered problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: I just spent hours trying to find/create something like this. Thanks so much!